# Show last table column on line hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

In a centered table is the last column hidden.
On hovering over a specific line I want the table to show the last column of this single line.
This should be offering the ability to edit and delete (AJAX) the content/object of the line.

Here's a example:
https://jsfiddle.net/5x2wv160/1/

The problem is the changed size of the table so it is moving a little bit to the left.

My idea fixing this is to change the  last column to

```
tr > td:last-child {    
    position: relative;
}
```

But what base element do I have to set the display-style too?

Does anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `visibility` instead of `dispay:none` like this:

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

tr > td:last-child {
  visibility: hidden;
}

tr:hover > td:last-child {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this way of showing the last column on hover to `<tr>`

```css
.action {
  display: none;
}

tr:hover .action{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content1</td>
      <td>Content2</td>
      <td class="action"><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content3</td>
      <td>Content4</td>
      <td class="action"><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content5</td>
      <td>Content6</td>
      <td class="action"><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: As you can see in my fiddle, the table is centered and because of this it is moving. I want to prevent the moving.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way. But how about only showing contents thus the hyperlink on hover. `tr td a { display:none; }` VS `tr:hover td a{ display:block}` so the content would not be moving left and right. Also setting standard widths for each table column would prevent that the columns are moving

Comment: But then is a empty column at the end of the table which is visually not very nice